# ActiveMQ, consumers with prefetch=0, increasing "Enqueues" count in console (because of polling?)

Tags: listener, activemq-classic, prefetch, consumer

Using Spring-configured ActiveMQ, with a listener configured with a prefetch=0 connectionFactory and 5-5 concurrency, we're seeing the listeners apparently poll for new messages instead of the broker pushing messages, as expected.

However, in the ActiveMQ web console for the "Active Listeners" of our queue, I see that the "Enqueues" column count continually rises at a rapid rate (about 1 every second). Is this normal behavior? Is this just reflecting each poll of the listeners for new messages, now that we have prefetch=0?  It just seems a bit strange that the queues are showing an increasing Enqueue count when there's no actual messages they're working. Was also wondering if there's a way to throttle the poll frequency, or have some delay before each consumer polls the broker for new messages.

Pic of the console, showing the ever-increasing Enqueue count of each consumer with prefetch=0, even when there's no messages to work:

http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/file/n4666021/enqueues.png

Comment: Your best bet is to test the latest release and if its not working as expected create a JUnit test case and attach that to a Jira issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but at this point I'm not sure if it's even an issue or bug. This may be perfectly normal behavior of a "prefetch=0" consumer (that it continuously increments its enqueue count) - but I don't know.

Comment: There are few bug with prefetch = 0 (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3992). Check your config and the changelogs (https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311210&version=12321258 or https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12311210&version=12323282)